# Why internal differences in Flash Player of Ubuntu and Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, chrome, adobe-flash

Test video https://twitter.com/NHL/status/740577888735526912. In Chromium

[image]

Unsuccessfuly attempts

- I followed the guide [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-chromium.html) > https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ > 64 bit apt Ubuntu 10+. After install, I get the notice you already have the plugin.
- `masi@masi:~$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flash-properties-gtk`
- `masi@masi:~$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

In Firefox, the .swf files work with the plugin `browser-plugin-gnash` however.

### Internal differences of two systems - Ubuntu's glue!

Please, see my answer about Debian 8.5 for the case where the hardware is more stable: Asus Zenbook UX303UA. 
The solution works with only a single package in Debian, while Ubuntu requires also the second package. 
This proposes me that there is something internal going on in Ubuntu, which should be profiled and fixed.

Flash Player: gnash 0.8.11
Internet browser: Chromium, 51.x, Google Chrome 52.x
System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnash can't work with Chromium. Uninstall it first before doing the following installation. The solution is to install Google's PepperFlash plugin (disclaimer: nonfree) and the freshplayer component:

```
sudo apt install pepperflashplugin-nonfree browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Comment: Please, see my answer below. I managed to solve the case without your first package in Debian 8.5. Note that you need both packages in Ubuntu 16.04. There is something internal going on, possibly wrong, in Ubuntu, because you need such fixes there but not in Debian.

Comment: I really want to understand why the situation can be solved by one package only. Note that the first package is removed from Debian's apt-get also.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Debian 8.5. Do as root where the first package of Raju's answer does not exist in Debian, but the following command works there without the package

```
apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Test videos: NHL [video](https://twitter.com/NHL/status/740577888735526912) about Joonas Donskoi, [here](http://yle.fi/uutiset/rantalomalle_maailman_vaarallisimpaan_maahan_syyria_julkaisi_matkailumainoksia__video/9149365) in Finnish main media
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 (backports)